# Script wont work on new sheets/spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have been using this script for months, but now i wanted to add it to another sheets or spreadsheet and its not working, on old sheets where it was added moths ago it works fine.
Script is for hiding empty rows and showing rows that has values.
Maybe someone have any idea what to change in script so that it works again?

```
     function hiderows() {


      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1YoInjxlCeBPZP0HlEW0HSYBkdMCGtRaeJFylCQNXnMM');
         sheets = ["Lapa1"]

        for (var s = 0; s < sheets.length; s++) {
            var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[s]);


      var firstRow = 1;  
      var firstCol = 1;  
      var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
      var show = null, map = [], index, flag;
      for (var i = firstRow - 1, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
        flag = false;
        for (var j = firstCol - 1, width = data[0].length; j < width; j++) {
          if (data[i][j] )  {
            flag = true;
            break;
          }

        }
        if (show === flag) {
          map[index].rows++;
        } else {
          index = i + 1;
          show = flag;
          map[index] = {rows: 1, show: show};
        }
      }
      for (

var i in map) {
    if (map[i].show) {
      sh.showRows(i, map[i].rows);
    } else {
      sh.hideRows(i, map[i].rows);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what is the script's intended purpose

Comment: Script is for hiding empty rows and showing rows that has values.

Comment: I assume you remember to change `SpreadsheetApp.openById('1YoInjxlCeBPZP0HlEW0HSYBkdMCGtRaeJFylCQNXnMM')` for any new spreadsheet

Comment: Of course :) i changed spredsheed ID and sheet name.
When i play script it hides only 1 row

Comment: Has anyone else tried this script if it works for you?

Comment: I've tried and it works fine for me. It hides all empty rows above and in the data range and shows any hidden rows containing data. Does the script throw any errors when you run it? can you share the execution transcript with us? View -> Execution transcript

Comment: Ok, it hides/shows rows in between data, but it wont hide rows that are empty at the bottom of the page. I have data till row 50, but have extra rows that should hide too.
Strange that in old sheet it hides those rows, but in new only those that are in between data ...

Comment: Unsuccessful execution:
[17-05-16 15:39:35:536 EEST] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([AK]) [0 s]
[17-05-16 15:39:35:630 EEST] Sheet.getDataRange() [0,094 s]
[17-05-16 15:39:35:695 EEST] Range.getValues() [0,064 s]
[17-05-16 15:39:35:794 EEST] Sheet.hideRows([1, 1]) [0,091 s]
[17-05-16 15:39:36:065 EEST] Sheet.showRows([2, 4]) [0,27 s]
[17-05-16 15:39:36:249 EEST] Sheet.hideRows([6, 1]) [0,183 s]
[17-05-16 15:39:36:462 EEST] Sheet.showRows([7, 198]) [0,213 s]
[17-05-16 15:39:36:463 EEST] Izpilde veiksmīga [kopējais izpildlaiks: 0,961 sekundes]